# Java Jsoup search

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I have some questions regarding Jsoup. 
I have the following parent page. I want to look for some tag names on a HTML page and if they found, I want go inside the linked tag names and search for more tag names. But first I want to give me the tag names in the console.
This is my HTML page.

```
    <div id="main">


<div class="box">
<!-- box / title -->
<div class="title">
<h5>
<input class="q_filter_box" id="q_filter" size="15" type="text" name="filter" placeholder="quick filter..." value=""/> 
<span class="groups_breadcrumbs">
<a href="/">Home</a>
&raquo; "samia" with
</span>
<span id="repo_count">0</span> repositories
</h5>
<ul class="links">
<li>

</li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- end box / title -->
<div class="table">
<div id='groups_list_wrap' class="yui-skin-sam">
<table id="groups_list">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="left"><a href="#">Section Name</a></th>
<th class="left"><a href="#">ID_Description</a></th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tr>
<td>
<div style="white-space: nowrap">
<a href="/samia/Export"><i class="icon-folder-close"></i> Export</a>
</div>
</td>
<td>samia/Export group</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div style="white-space: nowrap">
<a href="/samia/Links"><i class="icon-folder-close"></i> Links</a>
</div>
</td>
<td>samia/Links group</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div style="white-space: nowrap">
<a href="/samia/Platforms"><i class="icon-folder-close"></i> Platforms</a>
</div>
</td>
<td>samia/Platforms group</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div style="white-space: nowrap">
<a href="/samia/LargeSml"><i class="icon-folder-close"></i> LargeSml</a>
</div>
</td>
<td>samia/LargeSml group</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div style="white-space: nowrap">
<a href="/samia/Processes"><i class="icon-folder-close"></i> Processes</a>
</div>
</td>
<td>samia/Processes group</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div style="white-space: nowrap">
<a href="/samia/Tills"><i class="icon-folder-close"></i> Tills</a>
</div>
</td>
<td>Tills für samia</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

First I want to look/display:
Export
Links
Platforms
LargeSml

Second I want to go inside of Export and search for more tags, etc....

I have following code so far, but it doesnt seem to work.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://************").cookies(loginCookies).get();


            for (Element table : doc.select("groups_list")) {
                for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
                    Elements tds = row.select("td");

                    System.out.println(tds.get(0).text());
                }
            }
```

Here is my second approach.
On the page I want navigate through the table groups_list for tag    Export, Links, Platforms etc. So if I under those sub-pages (like Export), I search for all links the name ending with Doc. These are however in javascript. Following the is the script.

```
      <script>
    var data = {"totalRecords": 2, "sort": "name", "startIndex": 0, "dir": "asc", "records": [{"raw_name": "samia/export/Citydata", "last_changeset": "\n  <div>\n      <pre><a title=\"xn00761:\n\nAdded tag V2.11.d50.mkt.001 for changeset 56e10a4864ff\" class=\"tooltip\" href=\"/samia/export/Citydata/changeset/f602409eba261d749d23dc75551b2959425dfa8d\">r17:f602409eba26</a></pre>\n  </div>\n", "atom": "\n    <a title=\"Subscribe to samia/export/Citydata atom feed\" href=\"/samia/export/Citydata/feed/atom?api_key=e214ebea2335318bee1460a1fd33725ab3e1002e\"><i class=\"icon-rss-sign\"  style=\"color: #fa9b39\"></i></a>\n", "owner": "owner", "rss": "\n    <a title=\"Subscribe to samia/export/Citydata rss feed\" href=\"/samia/export/Citydata/feed/rss?api_key=e214ebea2335318bee1460a1fd33725ab3e1002e\"><i class=\"icon-rss-sign\" style=\"color: #fa9b39\"></i></a>\n", "name": "\n    \n  <div style=\"white-space: nowrap; }\">\n        <a href=\"/samia/export/Citydata\">\n\n        <span title=\"Mercurial repository\"><i class=\"icon-hg\" style=\"color: #316293; font-size: 14px;\"></i></span>\n\n      <span style=\"margin: 0px 8px 0px 8px\"></span>\n    Citydata\n    </a>\n  </div>\n", "last_rev_raw": 17, "state": "\n  <div>\n        <div class=\"btn btn-mini btn-success disabled\">Created</div>\n  </div>\n", "menu": "\n  <ul class=\"menu_items hidden\">\n\n    <li style=\"border-top:1px solid #003367;margin-left:18px;padding-left:-99px\"></li>\n    <li>\n       <a title=\"Summary\" href=\"/samia/export/Citydata\">\n       <span class=\"icon\">\n           <i class=\"icon-file-text\"></i>\n       </span>\n       <span>Summary</span>\n       </a>\n    </li>\n    <li>\n       <a title=\"Changelog\" href=\"/samia/export/Citydata/changelog\">\n       <span class=\"icon\">\n           <i class=\"icon-list-alt\"></i>\n       </span>\n       <span>Changelog</span>\n       </a>\n    </li>\n    <li>\n       <a title=\"Files\" href=\"/samia/export/Citydata/files/tip/\">\n       <span class=\"icon\">\n           <i class=\"icon-file-alt\"></i>\n       </span>\n       <span>Files</span>\n       </a>\n    </li>\n    <li>\n       <a title=\"Fork\" href=\"/samia/export/Citydata/fork\">\n       <span class=\"icon\">\n           <i class=\"icon-code-fork\"></i>\n       </span>\n       <span>Fork</span>\n       </a>\n    </li>\n  </ul>\n", "desc": "HDB Marktdatenimport", "last_change": "\n  <span class=\"tooltip\" date=\"2014-08-21 18:49:50\" title=\"Thu, 21 Aug 2014 18:49:50\">6 days and 19 hours ago</span>\n"}, {"raw_name": "samia/export/CitydataDoc", "last_changeset": "\n  <div>\n      <pre><a title=\"xn01606 &amp;lt;owner;gt;:\n\nChangedokumentation\" class=\"tooltip\" href=\"/samia/export/CitydataDoc/changeset/9ed1679c7a35b76e1402b540cee38000461fdfdd\">r0:9ed1679c7a35</a></pre>\n  </div>\n", "atom": "\n    <a title=\"Subscribe to samia/export/CitydataDoc atom feed\" href=\"/samia/export/CitydataDoc/feed/atom?api_key=e214ebea2335318bee1460a1fd33725ab3e1002e\"><i class=\"icon-rss-sign\"  style=\"color: #fa9b39\"></i></a>\n", "owner": "xn00761 (Stefan Kortmann)", "rss": "\n    <a title=\"Subscribe to samia/export/CitydataDoc rss feed\" href=\"/samia/export/CitydataDoc/feed/rss?api_key=e214ebea2335318bee1460a1fd33725ab3e1002e\"><i class=\"icon-rss-sign\" style=\"color: #fa9b39\"></i></a>\n", "name": "\n    \n  <div style=\"white-space: nowrap; }\">\n        <a href=\"/samia/export/CitydataDoc\">\n\n        <span title=\"Mercurial repository\"><i class=\"icon-hg\" style=\"color: #316293; font-size: 14px;\"></i></span>\n\n      <span style=\"margin: 0px 8px 0px 8px\"></span>\n    CitydataDoc\n    </a>\n  </div>\n", "last_rev_raw": 0, "state": "\n  <div>\n        <div class=\"btn btn-mini btn-success disabled\">Created</div>\n  </div>\n", "menu": "\n  <ul class=\"menu_items hidden\">\n\n    <li style=\"border-top:1px solid #003367;margin-left:18px;padding-left:-99px\"></li>\n    <li>\n       <a title=\"Summary\" href=\"/samia/export/CitydataDoc\">\n       <span class=\"icon\">\n           <i class=\"icon-file-text\"></i>\n       </span>\n       <span>Summary</span>\n       </a>\n    </li>\n    <li>\n       <a title=\"Changelog\" href=\"/samia/export/CitydataDoc/changelog\">\n       <span class=\"icon\">\n           <i class=\"icon-list-alt\"></i>\n       </span>\n       <span>Changelog</span>\n       </a>\n    </li>\n    <li>\n       <a title=\"Files\" href=\"/samia/export/CitydataDoc/files/tip/\">\n       <span class=\"icon\">\n           <i class=\"icon-file-alt\"></i>\n       </span>\n       <span>Files</span>\n       </a>\n    </li>\n    <li>\n       <a title=\"Fork\" href=\"/samia/export/CitydataDoc/fork\">\n       <span class=\"icon\">\n           <i class=\"icon-code-fork\"></i>\n       </span>\n       <span>Fork</span>\n       </a>\n    </li>\n  </ul>\n", "desc": "HDB Marktdatenimport (Dokumentation)", "last_change": "\n  <span class=\"tooltip\" date=\"2014-04-25 11:03:45\" title=\"Fri, 25 Apr 2014 11:03:45\">4 months and 3 days ago</span>\n"}]};
    var myDataSource = new YAHOO.util.DataSource(data);
    myDataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_JSON;
```

When I then go under all these ...Doc links, I want look if there are more links with specific tag. Here below you see, I want navigate through all links within tag name "r0:9ed1679c7a35"

```
<div class="box" style="margin-top: -20px">
<div class="title">
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
        <a href="/samia/Export/CitydataDoc/changelog">Latest changes</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table">
    <div id="shortlog_data">
        <table class="table_disp">
<tr>
    <th class="left">Revision</th>
    <th class="left">Commit message</th>
    <th class="left">Age</th>
    <th class="left">Author</th>
    <th class="left">Refs</th>
</tr>
<tr class="parity0">
    <td>
      <div>
        <div class="changeset-status-container">
        </div>
        <pre><a href="/samia/Export/CitydataDoc/files/9ed1679c7a35b76e1402b540cee38000461fdfdd/">r0:9ed1679c7a35</a></pre>
     </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a class="message-link" href="/samia/Export/CitydataDoc/changeset/9ed1679c7a35b76e1402b540cee38000461fdfdd">Changedokumentation</a>
    </td>
    <td><span class="tooltip" title="Fri, 25 Apr 2014 11:03:45">
                  4 months and 3 days ago</span>
    </td>
    <td title="owner;">owner</td>
    <td>
         <div class="tagtag" title="Tag tip">
             <a href="/samia/Export/CitydataDoc/files/9ed1679c7a35b76e1402b540cee38000461fdfdd/">tip</a>
         </div>
         <div class="branchtag" title="Branch default">
             <a href="/samia/Export/CitydataDoc/changelog?branch=default">default</a>
         </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

When I am under the links of the one called "r0:9ed1679c7a35", I have the following HTML code. Here I want to navigate through Changedokumentation.docx.

```
<div class="browser-body">
    <table class="code-browser">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Size</th>
                <th>Mimetype</th>
                <th>Last Revision</th>
                <th>Last modified</th>
                <th>Last committer</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody id="tbody">

            <tr class="parity0">
                 <td>

    <a class="browser-file ypjax-link" href="/samia/Export/CitydataDoc/files/9ed1679c7a35b76e1402b540cee38000461fdfdd/Changedokumentation_P0702_HDB_20140318.docx">Changedokumentation.docx</a>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     133.5 KiB
                 </td>
                 <td>
                      application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
                 </td>
                 <td>
                         <div class="tooltip" title="Changedokumentation">
                          <pre>r0:9ed1679c7a35</pre>
                         </div>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                         <span class="tooltip" title="Fri, 25 Apr 2014 11:03:45">
                        4 months and 3 days ago</span>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                         <span title="owner">
                        owner
                        </span>
                 </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody id="tbody_filtered" style="display:none">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And finally when I am at the End-page I want the Names first listed (so I know that this file is existing) and also have the option to download the file. I can download it when the "Download as Raw" is pressed. This is here in the code.

```
<div id="body" class="codeblock">
<div class="code-header">
    <div class="stats">
        <div class="left img"><i class="icon-file"></i></div>
        <div class="left item"><pre class="tooltip" title="Fri, 25 Apr 2014 11:03:45"><a href="/samia/Export/CityDataDoc/changeset/9ed1679c7a35b76e1402b540cee38000461fdfdd">r0:9ed1679c7a35</a></pre></div>
        <div class="left item"><pre>133.5 KiB</pre></div>
        <div class="left item last"><pre>application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document</pre></div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <a class="btn btn-mini" href="/samia/Export/CityDataDoc/annotate/9ed1679c7a35b76e1402b540cee38000461fdfdd/Changedokumentation.docx">Show Annotation</a>
          <a class="btn btn-mini" href="/samia/Export/CityDataDoc/raw/9ed1679c7a35b76e1402b540cee38000461fdfdd/Changedokumentation.docx">Show as Raw</a>
          <a class="btn btn-mini" href="/samia/Export/CityDataDoc/rawfile/9ed1679c7a35b76e1402b540cee38000461fdfdd/Changedokumentation.docx">Download as Raw</a>
            <a class="btn btn-mini disabled tooltip" href="#" title="Editing binary files not allowed">Edit</a>
            <a class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" href="/samia/Export/CityDataDoc/delete/default/Changedokumentation.docx#edit">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="author">
        <div class="gravatar">
            <img alt="gravatar" src="/images/user16.png"/>
        </div>
        <div title="owner" class="user">owner</div>
    </div>
    <div class="commit">Changedokumentation</div>
</div>
<div class="code-body">
       <div style="padding:5px">
       Binary file (application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document)
       </div>
</div>
```

I know that is too much code. But it is pretty easy to understand, I hope :-)

Comment: Try `doc.select("id=groups_list")`

Comment: Hi Pphoenix,
where should I place this?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand at all your problem. You use words that are not very clear to me. note that if your site loads content via AJAX and constructs HTML nodes via JavaScript you can't easily use JSOUP. Maybe a selenium approach can help you. Read up on these things. Also read about css selectors.

Comment: I just want to navigate thorugh all those sub-pages and if the files are existing, I want to download them into my local PC. Thats all. I thought I can navigate through webpages via parsing or patching with Jsoup. I have nothing to do with Ajax.

Comment: Can anyone else help?
Thanks for looking luksch anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [css like selectors in JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html). the way you use it, it searches for an element tag called `groups_list`, which is of course not found. Instead you need to look for a `table` with id `groups_list`. This would do it I think:

```
doc.select("table#groups_list")
```

Put this in the outer loop and you should at least get the `td` elements printed out.

Since in html documents, the id should be unique, you can do also:

```
doc.select("#groups_list")
```

or

```
doc.select("table[id=groups_list]")
```

finally, if you don't want to use the css select engine of JSOUP, you may use the JSOUP methods for directly accessing elements by id:

```
doc.getElementById("groups_list");
```

Comment: Sorry, if I change it into
for (Element table : doc.select("table#groups_list")) {
                 for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
                     Elements tds = row.select("td");

I receive the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
 at org.jsoup.select.Elements.get(Elements.java:544)
 at test.GetElement.main(GetElement.java:30)

Comment: it seems in doc there is no element ```table``` with id ```groups_list```. Are you sure you have the correct url loaded? Oyu can check by printing out the page source after you fetch the url

Comment: There is actually the table id. Please, look in the HTML code again

<table id="groups_list">

Comment: I see the html you gave, but does your program have the same html string before the loop starts?

Comment: Sorry I dont know what you are meaning, see below my code.

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

  Response res = Jsoup
    .connect(
      "myurl")
    .data("username", "*", "password", "*")
    .method(Method.POST).execute();
  Map<String, String> loginCookies = res.cookies();

  Document doc = Jsoup.connect("myurl")
    .cookies(loginCookies).get();

  for (Element table : doc.select("table#groups_list")) {
   for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
    Elements tds = row.select("td");

    System.out.println(tds.get(0).text());
   }
  }
 }

Comment: @user3676199 What he meant was that you should check the `doc` you get when calling `Document doc =Jsoup.connect("myurl") .cookies(loginCookies).get()`. It is possible that the doc you retrieve does not contain the `<table id=...>` from the website, perhaps due to a login error.

Comment: Oh OK, the login works fine and when I call the html body like that
´code´ System.out.println(doc.body().html());
I get indeed the table id like      <table id="groups_list">

Comment: @luksch,
I succeeded with the my first approach and need idea how to do it in my next approach, which is...
Second I want to go inside of Export and search for more tags, etc....
Could you help in me in that please

Comment: If your question was answered I would appreciate if you accept the answer. If you find it helpful you may also up-vote it. New questions should be asked in a separate question - make sure you explain what you are having problems with.

Comment: Hi @luksch 
my question is not fully answered I am afraid. I need ideas how to navigate through the webpages to find e.g. in 4th child page a tag. Would you please help?

Comment: Sorry dude, I don't understand you. Try to update your question and explain what you have so far and what you try to do. I would like to help, but I have no idea what you are actually asking.